# Must hide one line / password in my Google Sheets script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I've created a Google Sheet that accepts input from the user, then based on that information, goes to an external website and automatically populates the spreadsheet.

My problem is that I want to hand over the google sheet and allow others to use it, however it contains my own personal API key to the external website.  It is unlikely that users will get their own API or know how/where to put it even if they do.

I want to allow them to use the sheet, but not be able to access or see the script, or at least my API key within the script.  But because the sheet requires their input, permissions must allow them to edit...and therefore, see/edit the script as well.

Part of the ToS of the external website is that it requires a registered API key in order to pull the information.  I can let anyone use the information when they use an application that contains the key, but I am not allowed to let anyone else know what the actual key is.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should create another Google Script with a doGet method and publish it as a web app. Here you can put the API key and pass the user input as a parameter.

The Google Sheet can call this script and API key will not be exposed to the end user. The web app can connect to the external API and return the results to the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to hide your API key.

> `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` - Gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

Comment: I guess this would make the script to fail when other users were calling it, which might not be intended. If he was the only one that would access the script there would be no need to hide it.